# RewriteCond and RewriteRule 301 redirect oscommerce htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am having duplicate urls.

First URL http://www.mydomain.com/product_info.php/cPath/34_128/products_id/2440

Second URL http://www.mydomain.com/product_info.php/products_id/2440

What are the .htaccess entries so that all urls in the first url will be 301 redirected to the second url

http://www.mydomain.com/product_info.php/products_id/2440

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try using either mod_alias (Redirect/RedirectMatch) or mod_rewrite (RewriteRule). If you already have rewrite rules somewhere, you may want to just stick with mod_rewrite otherwise there may be conflicts.

mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /product_info.php/cPath/ /product_info.php/
```

mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?product_info.php/cPath/(.*)$ /product_info.php/$1 [L,R=301]
```